How to write a Snowflake stored procedure that inserts data into another table based on left join and also returns the queried data as a table
I am new to Snowflake. I am going to ask you based on my SQL Server knowledge.

I need a to write a Stored procedure in Snowflake that return top N rows from Table A left joined with Table B.
It inserts the key field (of Table A) from above query into another table say Table B. So that next time when we call this stored procedure the same N rows will not be returned.
It also returns the results from Step 1 as a result set so it can be consumed using C#

There is a Post that describes how to return resultset
How do you Create Snowflake Procedure that returns Table?
I am struggling to understand if I may be able to use this result set to insert data into another table (Table B) in my case , before returning the data.
Appreciate any help.

I don't see any reason why this couldn't be done in a stored procedure, but it'd help on this site to include your attempt at it, rather than just asking for somebody to write it for you.  The key is to find the language that you are most comfortable with and start there?  If you are SQL Server, then Snowflake scripting is a bit different, but the closest thing.  I prefer Snowpark Python, personally....and I came from SQL Server, as well.

As per the Stackoverflow Post referenced above:
We may return a Resultset (results) as a Table using TABLE(results).
It seems we need to use a cursor to iterate over the RESULTSET, is my understanding correct?
Can we just read columns from the Resultset/Table in the Stored Procedure and insert into another table?
